# Ubuntu 13.04: "Failed to fetch.." when running update. Is this package important?

Tags: 13.04, updates, package-management, ppa

`W:Failed to fetch       http://ppa.launchpad.net/chicharreros/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

That was the message I got. If the package is important, how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the specific PPA you are trying to reach there is outdated, or discontinued based on the error message you are receiving.

Pop open a terminal and navigate to

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Find the offending PPA and delete the  file.

If your apt list is stopping at a certain object, it will then fail to reach the end of the list, meaning you may be missing out on some upgrades for packages that are further along in the sources.list

EDIT: This page, https://launchpad.net/~chicharreros/+archive/ppa seems to suggest support only goes as high as Ubuntu 11.04 which may be why you're having issues